# How to I specify companys custom boot image in Terraform script?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, virtual-machine, terraform-provider-gcp

I'm currently learning terraform and I'am unable to set a basic VM via terraform using one of my companys custom boot image.

If i was to do it manually on a GCP page during creaton of VM instance I woud click "Boot disk" -> click on "Custom images" tab -> click on "Show images from" -> chose specifc project from drop down menu -> click on "Image" -> chose the right image from drop down menu

but I don't know how to traslate it to terraform script

```
provider "google" {
  project = "xxxxxx"
}
resource "google_compute_instance" "xxxxxx" {
  name         = "xxxxxx"
  machine_type = "xxxxxx"
  zone         = "xxxxxx"

  boot_disk {
    initialize_params {
      image = "???"
    }
  }
  metadata_startup_script = ";;"
  network_interface {
    network = "default"
   }
}
```

Comment: What is the issue? The script looks good. Just replace the ??? with your image name.

Comment: I've tried replacing it with image name or project_name/image_name but none of this works.I always get error message:
Error: Error resolving image name 'project_name/name_of_the_image': Could not find image or family project_name/name_of_the_image   .                         The desired image is custom, and belongs to different project (not the same project I'm trying to create VM in)

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if this works, but you can give a try:

Since you will need to access multiple projects, I would set multiple [providers](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/providers/configuration.html) with an alias:

```
provider "google" {
  project     = "project-A"
  region      = "us-central1"
  credentials = "path-to-your-service-account"
  alias       = "main_provider"
}

# this is where your image is
provider "google" {
  project     = "project-B"
  region      = "us-central1"
  credentials = "path-to-your-service-account"
  alias       = "image_source_provider"
}
```

then use the [google_compute_image](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/data-sources/compute_image) to get the image you want:

```
data "google_compute_image" "my_image" {
  name    = "name-of-your-image-from-project-B"
  project = "project-B"
}
```

and finally use it in your [google_compute_instance](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/compute_instance):

```
resource "google_compute_instance" "xxxxxx" {
  name         = "xxxxxx"
  machine_type = "xxxxxx"
  zone         = "xxxxxx"
  provider     = google.main_provider

  boot_disk {
    initialize_params {
      image = data.google_compute_image.my_image.self_link
    }
  }
  metadata_startup_script = ";;"
  network_interface {
    network = "default"
   }
}
```

Comment: [@Pawel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15242528/pawel-herbert) - did this solve your issue ?